# JAVA : How to resize JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to change the size of a `JPanel`. I tried `setSize` (solutions proposed in this forum) but it did not work for me.

`JFrame` code:

```
JFrame f =new JFrame();
f.setTitle("test");
f.setSize(300,400);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setResizable(false);
f.setLayout(null);
```

`JPanel` code:

```
 JPanel display= new JPanel();
 display.setLayout(null);
 JTextField txt = new JTextField(30);
 display.add(txt,BorderLayout.NORTH);
 display.setBackground(Color.gray);
 display.setSize(30,17);
```

Comment: You could use `setPreferredSize()` and method like this but if the layout of the frame or whatever you added the panel to is managed by a layout manager this would be ultimately responsible for the the size. Ideally don't call `display.setLayout(null);`, i.e. keep the original layout manager or replace it with something sensible and let it figure out the panel's preferred size from the panel's contents.

Comment: As @Thomas said you should use a proper layout. Still, the problem is not in this piece of code so probably you're doing something else wrong when creating the Frame.

Comment: Please don't add info via comments or answers but [edit] your question. You might also read [ask].

Comment: So your frame doesn't have a layout manager as well? If you added the panel then have a lookat the `setBounds()` method that sets position and size.

Comment: i try it ,still don't work for me

Comment: Why does display have a null layout, but you're adding a text field with a BorderLayout constant. Where do you add your display to the frame? Can you show your code with the setBounds call? Your size is really tiny too.

Comment: *i tried setSize (solutions proposed in this forum* - people in the forum would not propose using setSize(). If anybody suggests using setSize() or setBounds() then you should ignore the suggestion and move on. The proper solution is to use a layout manager. The layout manager will determine the size and location of each component based on the rules of the layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a complete and compilable example doing what you're trying to do.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ResizableJPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" with a panel");
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.setLayout(null);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque( true);
        panel.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        panel.setBounds( 200, 200, 400, 400);
        
        content.add(panel);        
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    
    }

}
```

You can change the values of the setBounds to move or resize the panel.

You've left out some important bits: How you add the panel to the JFrame? What is wrong with your current method?

If you're text field isn't showing up, it is because your JPanel is very small, and it has a null layout.

```
panel.setLayout(null);
JTextField field = new JTextField(30);
panel.add(field);
field.setBounds( 50, 110, 30, 17 );
```

That would add the field and give it a size. **It's bad to use a null layout here** because a layout manager will take care of the size of the TextField.

Comment: i use setcontentpane to add panel to a jframe, i'm a beginner and i don't understand why do you use add instead of setcontentpane

Comment: when i use frame.add to add panel , it work sometime and sometime the programme just show me an empty window when execution.

Comment: @hepona There is a bit of ambiguity in the API. The JFrame has methods that operate on the content pane, eg. [JFrame.setLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setLayout(java.awt.LayoutManager)) is essentially: `jframe.getContentPane().setLayout()`. I like to be explicit. Since I used the existing content pane I didn't have to get it again. For the second question, it would be best to see the complete code. (maybe even a new question?) Also, does it appear when you resize the window?